# I am getting following Error on startup of weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java

java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReaderWarning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader 
Warning: Exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
Warning: I will print the stack trace then carry on using the default SAX parser

```
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.setFeature(SAXReader.java:218)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addXMLEntities(Ejb3Configuration.java:438)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:360)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:39)
at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:349)
at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:124)
at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1827)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:3029)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:448)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addXMLEntities(Ejb3Configuration.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
    at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:39)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:349)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:124)
    at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1827)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:3029)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:448)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Warning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader 
Warning: Exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
Warning: I will print the stack trace then carry on using the default SAX parser

> 

What is the best way to fix the above error.

My weblogic.xml file as follows.......

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    10.3.6
        RatingsBD

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

does any one have solution for that......
Please help me out i'm wondering..........

Answer (score 1):

this error is due to some problem in weblogic.xml

1) you may be uploading your application from some remote system
so first copy the war or ear in the same system in which weblogic is installed

2) there may be space in between tags in `weblogic.xml`

3) you are using `weblogic.xml` of some older version generate a new xml may be through eclipse

Comment: Hi Hemat, I am running project on eclipse Kepler not uploading application from any remote system. I also verify the weblogic.xml its latest and eclipse generated itself. Im getting above error while starting Weblogic 11g server.Does missed out anything else.

Comment: Thanks Hemant. Issue get resolved by adding below linesC:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1v here in common/lib I added this jar and added set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar code in /common/bin/commEnv.cmd and

Comment: Actualy main issue is Named Query which get resolved by configuring  above lines.

Comment: ohh so it is due to antlr me to faced the same issue . my application was not able to get hibernate connection. and always use to return null so you may be getting a **hql token error** in application logs.